# Spring resources mvc tag issue

Tags: java, spring, maven

Iam working with spring maven hibernate . I have error in adding resources mvc tag in dispatcher servlet file.For adding css and images files i have to add my folders using resources tag for that i have added xmlns mvc and its schema location. But its not working. Below am adding my code. When i remove mvc and resources from it , its working.

Please help.

```
<beans
 xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
<!-- Enable annotation driven controllers, validation etc... -->
 <import resource="classpath:ApplicationContext.xml"/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.org.rolltickets" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix"><value>/views/</value></property>
<property name="suffix"><value>.jsp</value></property>
</bean>

<bean id="appUserDao"  class="com.org.rolltickets.publicapp.dao.impl.AppUserDaoImpl" >
<property name="sessionFactory">
<ref bean="sessionFactory" />
</property>
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
</beans>
```

My images folder is inside webapp/images and css webapp/css. The folders are not inside resources folder of maven. How can i add these external folders as resources?

Comment: Please clarify what isn't working, currently that isn't clear.

Comment: when i go to url localhost/project/index it shows HTTP Status 404 -

Comment: And what is the relation to your resource mapping. There is no mapping (as I see ) for /index. Or you must have a controller which sends to a wrong jsp.

Comment: iam using annotaion @resource-mapping /index as i said when i remove the resource portion from my dispatcher servlet its working fine. Just remove the mvc related tags its fine. Thanks for the reply M.Denium.